# Python import files from 3 layers

Tags: python-3.x, python-import

I have the following file structure

```
home/user/app.py
home/user/content/resource.py
home/user/content/call1.py
home/user/content/call2.py
```

I have imported resources.py in app.py as below:

```
import content.resource
```

Also, I have imported call1 and call2 in resource.py

```
import call1
import call2
```

The requirement is to run two tests individually.

1. run app.py
2. run resource.py

When I run `app.py`, it says cannot find call1 and call2.
When run `resource.py`, the file is running without any issues. How to run `app.py` python file to call import functions in resource.py and also `call1.py` and `call2.py` files?

All the 4 files having `__init__` main function.

Comment: It works if I bring resource.py file outside the content directory. But I want to maintain the current directory structure.

Answer (score 0):

In your `__init__` files, just create a list like this for each init, so for your user `__init__`: `__all__ = ["app", "content"]`

And for your content `__init__`: `__all__ = ["resource", "call1", "call2"]`

First try: `export PYTHONPATH=/home/user`<-- Make sure this is the correct absolute path.

If that doesn't solve the issue, try adding `content` to the path as well.

try: `export PYTHONPATH=/home/user/:/home/user/content/`

This should definitely work.

You will then import like so:

`import user.app`

`import user.content.resource`

### NOTE

Whatever you want to use, you must import in every file. Don't bother importing in `__init__`. Just mention whatever modules that `__init__` includes by doing `__all__ = []`

Comment: Having set __all__=[list files and directories] have solved the issue. Able to run app.py and resource.py individually. Thanks for the resolution.

Answer (score 0):

You have to import call1 and call2 in app.py if you want to call them there.